# MySql does not start on Debian 5 VPS server

Tags: mysql, unix, debian, vps

I have a 128MB RAM VPS server. I have Debian 32bit OS running on it and I have decided to install some light weight LAMP, so I installed lighthttpd and MySQL but then it had to be started It said it was starting.... and failed. I tried to look to error logs but they are clean. What could it be?

Then I ask my hosting provider about it they just told me to buy more expensive plan because this one just  cannot possibly run MySQL because there is not enough ram. But I was aiming for server which could run with 96MB ram server!

Comment: in my.cnf/my.ini it's written than minimum 128MB, so i think you should consider to buy some RAM

Answer (score 0):

I just installed MySQL server on my CentOS VPS... it's running at about 180MB RAM. Out of the box. Sounds like you gotta upgrade. It's almost certainly a RAM issue as your provider mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably running a default mysql config that isn't tuned for a smaller RAM footprint.  You should probably use the my-small config (`/usr/share/doc/mysql-server-5.*/examples/my-small.cnf`) which is billed as being for "<=64M".  I don't warrant that it'll perform at all well, but it should at least start.

I wouldn't be trying to run anything production in 128MB of RAM these days, there's just too much bloat on a modern system, but if you're up for a challenge, have at it.  Oh, and replace lighttpd with nginx; sorry to all the lighttpd fans out there, but you've been superceded.

Comment: I tried to replace the my.cnf file with the one you mentioned but then I tried to start MySQL server again but it failed again.

Comment: Error messages, log messages, or any other useful diagnostic data?  Edit your question to add them.  You're probably hitting a change in iblogfile* size; delete those and try again.

Comment: As I mentioned before all the error logs are clean so I do not have anything to post.

Comment: If MySQL isn't starting, it's *definitely* logging something, you're just not looking in the right place.